# Spring Security: Create Users

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using spring-web(4.0.3.RELEASE) along with spring-security-web(3.2.3.RELEASE) in an app.  My goal is to automatically create some users when my application starts up.  However, when I add the users using the "security:user..." tag, it either doesn't create the users, or it complains that

```
Configuration problem: authentication-provider element cannot have 
child elements when used with 'ref' attribute
```

As of now, my security-config.xml file looks like so.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
   xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">
<security:http auto-config='true'>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/messagebroker/amf" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/login.json" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS" />
</security:http>
<jpa:repositories base-package="com.thing.orlando.repositories" />

 <!--authentication manager and password hashing-->
<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <security:authentication-provider ref="daoAuthenticationProvider">
        <security:user-service>
            <security:user name="admin" password="password" authorities="ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN" />
            <security:user name="user" password="password" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
        </security:user-service>
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>

<bean id="daoAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
    <property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService"/>
    <property name="saltSource">
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.ReflectionSaltSource">
            <property name="userPropertyToUse" value="email"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="passwordEncoder" ref="passwordEncoder"/>
</bean>

<bean id="userDetailsService"  name="userAuthenticationProvider"
      class="com.dallas.orlando.services.CustomUserDetailsService"/>
<bean id="passwordEncoder" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.ShaPasswordEncoder">
    <constructor-arg index="0" value="256"/>
</bean>
```

I was wondering what is the accepted way to create users and populate my db.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change to this:

```
<!--authentication manager and password hashing-->
<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <security:authentication-provider ref="daoAuthenticationProvider"/>
    <security:authentication-provider    
        <security:user-service>
            <security:user name="admin" password="password" authorities="ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN" />
            <security:user name="user" password="password" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
        </security:user-service>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

You need to specify your `daoAuthenticationProvider` as a separate authentication provider to your `user-service` authentication provider, because they should be providing two different methods of dealing with an authentication attempt.

Your `daoAuthenticationProvider` will do your own custom thing to determine whether to authenticate a login attempt, and the `user-service` will successfully authenticate the two users you gave it.

To answer your question: Create users using an SQL script when the application starts. You can use the SQL scripts like this:

```
<jdbc:initialize-database>
    <jdbc:script location="script.location.sql"/>
</jdbc:initialize-database>
```

You can list as many script files as you like.

If you want to add support for encrypted passwords use the BCrypt password encoder like this:

```
<beans:bean id="passwordEncoder"
    class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder" />
```

You can autowire this bean into your `daoAuthenticationProvider` and use it to check if the password input matches what's stored in the database. You can also just hardcode the password for any users you create in a script to just be the hashed version of 'asdf123' if you like. Its up to you in the end.

Comment: I've tried that and I did it again per your response.  In this scenario, no users are created.  Looking at the logs, I can see Hibernate creating the tables, but not instances of "Insert blach.." is found. =(

Comment: Because those two users are only stored in-memory. If you want to store them in a database, you'd need to use an SQL script to insert the data when the application starts up. Can you log into the application using those user's?

Comment: Did it work? If it didn't there's more things to try.

Comment: Looks like I am going to have to use a simple script to do what I need to.  I was worried about introducing brittleness between the userPropertyToUse/salt/password combination, but I may have to do that to make it work.  I'll try again tomorrow.

Comment: Why don't you just inject a password encoder? Spring has built-in support for the BCrypt password encoder.

Comment: The solution I went with was to use the import sql statement.  I'm not a fan of it, but it allows me to continue onward with my toy project and that's what really matters.

Comment: Glad I could help. I found Spring so confusing when I started, but now I'm fairly familiar with it, things start to make sense.